# background-size fallback for IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, menuitem

I have this [menu here](http://luigisettembrini.gov.it/). I set a background-image for each parent li (then I set an high value for the height of the background-size because the sub-menu has some entries on 2 lines, and a high value for the height compensate that). The problem is that IE doesn't support background-size, so I get this:

[image: IE issue]

How can I solve this? I tried to create a background-image with a higher height, but doesn't change anything.

Comment: Which version of IE you tried, it is coming in single line i tried in IE9, same effect in FF also

Comment: I tried with MSIE 7 and 8 (on 9 and 10 should work).

Comment: There is no color fade, right? Why don't you try to create a 1x1px large image and simply "repeat" that?

Comment: background-size introduced in CSS3, which doesn't supported by IE7 and IE8, you can do as prince Cherusker suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your image is a solid color, you can just remove the `background-size` and `background-repeat: none` (ie. let it repeat).

Alternately, you could do away with the `background-image` and use a background color with transparency:

```
.test {
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255); // solid white fallback for old browsers
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); // 50% transparent white
}
```

Comment: This seems the cleanest solution! I replaced all with rgb/rgba. In the other browsers everything work properly, in IE there's this problem (background-color isn't inherited by submenu): http://img254.imageshack.us/img254/5063/provayx.jpg

Comment: Did you place the color on the `li` or the `a`?  You have it on the `a` on the live version.  See if moving it to the `li` helps.

Comment: Oh ok fixed, it was my fault. On the fallback CSS for IE I had it on #menu-item-XXX, nor the a or the li. :)

Answer (score 2):

IE does support `background-size` as of IE9. For IE8 and lower, you can try [background-size polyfill](https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill). It seems your case does not need `background-size` at all though. Just use `rgba()` for IE9+ and repeated PNG-24 background for IE8-.